# Vmware Player 15

Tags: vmware

I am trying to run a virtual machine with a prebuild image in vmware player 15.

Any vm I try to run fails. All of them fail.

Below is the log. I hope someone can assist.

```
2020-01-27T15:10:53.484-07:00| vmx| I125: Log for VMware Player pid=8667 version=15.5.1 build=build-15018445 option=Release
2020-01-27T15:10:53.484-07:00| vmx| I125: The process is 64-bit.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.484-07:00| vmx| I125: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2020-01-27T15:10:53.484-07:00| vmx| I125: Host is Linux 5.3.0-26-generic Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: VTHREAD 140720181627840 "vmx" tid 8667
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/etc/vmware/vsphereFeatures/techPreview.cfg": No such file or directory.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/etc/vmware/vsphereFeatures/techPreview.cfg": No such file or directory.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: FeatureStateLib: Error while loading tech preview config file: /etc/vmware/vsphereFeatures/techPreview.cfg, using default (disabled) for all Tech Preview features.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: LOCALE en_US.UTF-8 -> NULL
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: Msg_SetLocaleEx: HostLocale=UTF-8 UserLocale=NULL
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: Msg_Reset:
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: ----------------------------------------
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: ConfigDB: Failed to load /usr/lib/vmware/settings
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/skullack/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: Msg_Reset:
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/home/skullack/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: ----------------------------------------
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: ConfigDB: Failed to load ~/.vmware/config
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: OBJLIB-LIB: Objlib initialized.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/home/skullack/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/home/skullack/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /home/skullack/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: Fail to realpath: /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.2-x86-64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2, errno=2
2020-01-27T15:10:53.464-07:00| vmx| I125: Denied library: /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.2-x86-64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2
2020-01-27T15:10:53.478-07:00| vmx| I125: lib/ssl: OpenSSL using FIPS_drbg for RAND
2020-01-27T15:10:53.478-07:00| vmx| I125: lib/ssl: protocol list tls1.2
2020-01-27T15:10:53.478-07:00| vmx| I125: lib/ssl: protocol list tls1.2 (openssl flags 0x17000000)
2020-01-27T15:10:53.478-07:00| vmx| I125: lib/ssl: cipher list ECDHE+AESGCM:RSA+AESGCM:ECDHE+AES:RSA+AES
2020-01-27T15:10:53.478-07:00| vmx| I125: lib/ssl: curves list prime256v1:secp384r1:secp521r1
2020-01-27T15:10:53.630-07:00| vmx| I125: Hostname=skullack-Vuln-Lab1
2020-01-27T15:10:53.630-07:00| vmx| I125: IP=127.0.0.1 (lo)
2020-01-27T15:10:53.630-07:00| vmx| I125: IP=192.168.20.246 (wlx00c0ca8def7a)
2020-01-27T15:10:53.630-07:00| vmx| I125: System uptime 3981230000 us
2020-01-27T15:10:53.630-07:00| vmx| I125: Command line: "/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx" "-ssnapshot.numRollingTiers=0" "-s" "vmx.stdio.keep=TRUE" "-#" "product=4;name=VMware Player;version=15.5.1;buildnumber=15018445;licensename=VMware Player;licenseversion=15.0+;" "-@" "duplex=3;msgs=ui" "/home/skullack/Desktop/Vuln_VM_HACKLAB/Kioptix Level 1.vmx"
2020-01-27T15:10:53.630-07:00| vmx| I125: Msg_SetLocaleEx: HostLocale=UTF-8 UserLocale=NULL
2020-01-27T15:10:53.630-07:00| vmx| I125: Duplex socket: 3
2020-01-27T15:10:53.653-07:00| vmx| I125: WQPoolAllocPoll : pollIx = 1, signalHandle = 9
2020-01-27T15:10:53.653-07:00| vmx| I125: WQPoolAllocPoll : pollIx = 2, signalHandle = 11
2020-01-27T15:10:53.653-07:00| vmx| I125: VigorTransport listening on fd 12
2020-01-27T15:10:53.653-07:00| vmx| I125: Vigor_Init 1
2020-01-27T15:10:53.653-07:00| vmx| I125: Connecting 'ui' to fd '3' with user '(null)'
2020-01-27T15:10:53.653-07:00| vmx| I125: VmdbAddConnection: cnxPath=/db/connection/#1/, cnxIx=1
2020-01-27T15:10:53.680-07:00| vmx| I125: /home/skullack/Desktop/Vuln_VM_HACKLAB/Kioptix Level 1.vmx: Setup symlink /var/run/vmware/35071bf3ad7f5bfa4a87ec34b4a14e05 -> /var/run/vmware/1000/3981230000_8667
2020-01-27T15:10:53.680-07:00| vmx| I125: Vix: [mainDispatch.c:486]: VMAutomation: Initializing VMAutomation.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.680-07:00| vmx| I125: Vix: [mainDispatch.c:738]: VMAutomationOpenListenerSocket() listening
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: Vix: [mainDispatch.c:4215]: VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished: statevar=0, newAppState=1870, success=1 additionalError=0
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: Transitioned vmx/execState/val to poweredOff
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: Vix: [mainDispatch.c:4215]: VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished: statevar=1, newAppState=1873, success=1 additionalError=0
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: Vix: [mainDispatch.c:4215]: VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished: statevar=2, newAppState=1877, success=1 additionalError=0
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: Vix: [mainDispatch.c:4215]: VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished: statevar=3, newAppState=1881, success=1 additionalError=0
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: FeatureCompat: No EVC masks.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID vendor: GenuineIntel
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID family: 0x6 model: 0x2a stepping: 0x7
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID codename: Sandy Bridge
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 00000000, 0: 0x0000000d 0x756e6547 0x6c65746e 0x49656e69
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 00000001, 0: 0x000206a7 0x06100800 0x1fbae3ff 0xbfebfbff
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 00000002, 0: 0x76035a01 0x00f0b0ff 0x00000000 0x00ca0000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 00000003, 0: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 00000004, 0: 0x1c004121 0x01c0003f 0x0000003f 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 00000004, 1: 0x1c004122 0x01c0003f 0x0000003f 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 00000004, 2: 0x1c004143 0x01c0003f 0x000001ff 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 00000004, 3: 0x1c03c163 0x02c0003f 0x00001fff 0x00000006
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 00000004, 4: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 00000005, 0: 0x00000040 0x00000040 0x00000003 0x00001120
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 00000006, 0: 0x00000075 0x00000002 0x00000009 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 00000007, 0: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x9c000400
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 00000008, 0: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 00000009, 0: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 0000000a, 0: 0x07300803 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000603
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 0000000b, 0: 0x00000001 0x00000001 0x00000100 0x00000006
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 0000000b, 1: 0x00000004 0x00000004 0x00000201 0x00000006
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 0000000b, 2: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000002 0x00000006
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 0000000c, 0: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 0000000d, 0: 0x00000007 0x00000340 0x00000340 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 0000000d, 1: 0x00000001 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.683-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 0000000d, 2: 0x00000100 0x00000240 0x00000000 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 80000000, 0: 0x80000008 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 80000001, 0: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000001 0x28100800
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 80000002, 0: 0x20202020 0x20202020 0x65746e49 0x2952286c
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 80000003, 0: 0x726f4320 0x4d542865 0x35692029 0x3034322d
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 80000004, 0: 0x50432030 0x20402055 0x30312e33 0x007a4847
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 80000005, 0: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 80000006, 0: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x01006040 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 80000007, 0: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000100
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: hostCPUID level 80000008, 0: 0x00003024 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: CPUID differences from hostCPUID.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Physical APIC IDs: 2,4,0,6
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Physical X2APIC IDs: 0,2,4,6
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR       0x3a =                0x1
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x480 =   0xda040000000010
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x481 =       0x7f00000016
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x482 = 0xfff9fffe0401e172
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x483 =   0x7fffff00036dff
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x484 =     0xffff000011ff
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x485 =         0x100401e5
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x486 =         0x80000021
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x487 =         0xffffffff
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x488 =             0x2000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x489 =            0x667ff
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x48a =               0x2a
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x48b =       0xff00000000
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x48c =      0xf0106114141
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x48d =       0x7f00000016
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x48e = 0xfff9fffe04006172
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x48f =   0x7fffff00036dfb
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x490 =     0xffff000011fb
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x491 =                  0
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR 0xc0010114 =                  0
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR       0xce =     0x100060011f00
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: Common: MSR      0x10a =                  0
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: UTIL: Change file descriptor limit from soft 4096,hard 4096 to soft 16384,hard 16384.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: VMMon_GetkHzEstimate: Calculated 3092972 kHz
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: TSC kHz estimates: vmmon 3092972, cpuinfo 2920953, cpufreq 3100000.  Using 3092972 kHz
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: TSC first measured delta 63
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: TSC min delta 32
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: PTSC: RefClockToPTSC 0 @ 1000000Hz -> 0 @ 3092972000Hz
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: PTSC: RefClockToPTSC ((x * 3243216208) >> 20) + -12210185695351
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: PTSC: tscOffset -12348709160862
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: PTSC: using TSC
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: PTSC: hardware TSCs are synchronized.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: PTSC: current PTSC=90776
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: WQPoolAllocPoll : pollIx = 3, signalHandle = 17
2020-01-27T15:10:53.684-07:00| vmx| I125: MKSXlib: Initialized thread-safe Xlib
2020-01-27T15:10:53.685-07:00| vmx| I125: [0x5602F1FD9000-0x5602F2D0BF02): /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-vmx
2020-01-27T15:10:53.769-07:00| vmx| I125: ConfigCheck: No rules file found. Checks are disabled.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.769-07:00| vmx| I125: changing directory to /home/skullack/Desktop/Vuln_VM_HACKLAB/.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.769-07:00| vmx| I125: Config file: /home/skullack/Desktop/Vuln_VM_HACKLAB/Kioptix Level 1.vmx
2020-01-27T15:10:53.769-07:00| vmx| I125: Vix: [mainDispatch.c:4215]: VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished: statevar=1, newAppState=1873, success=1 additionalError=0
2020-01-27T15:10:53.770-07:00| vmx| I125: Vix: [mainDispatch.c:4215]: VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished: statevar=2, newAppState=1878, success=1 additionalError=0
2020-01-27T15:10:53.795-07:00| vmx| W115: PowerOn
2020-01-27T15:10:53.795-07:00| vmx| I125: VMX_PowerOn: VMX build 15018445, UI build 15018445
2020-01-27T15:10:53.795-07:00| vmx| I125: libnuma.so found and in use.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.797-07:00| vmx| I125: NUMA topology found.
2020-01-27T15:10:53.797-07:00| vmx| I125: NUMA node 0: 7849MB, cpus 0x0000000f 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
```

Comment: Editing tips are at http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code   - if you would consider clicking [edit], removing what you have in that block of unformatted text, and repasting the log between ``` at top and bottom of the block, it would be far easier to read

Comment: NO need to comment - I did not have my bois settings setup for Virtualization its working now.

Comment: Murphy is everywhere.